# Does Goldbach's Conjecture Imply This?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Every natural number $\geq 4$ is centered between a pair of primes or is itself prime. Is this implied by Goldbach's conjecture?

Comment: Yes. Actually, every natural number$>0$.

Comment: @ChenJiang: When I say that $n$ is centered between a pair of primes, I mean that $n+a=p$ and $n-a=p$. Example: 4-1=3 and 4+1=5. On the natural number line 1,2,3,4,5... 4 is centered between 3 and 5.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. For $n$ to be centered around two primes, it must be the average of two primes. That is $$2n = p+q$$

If Goldbach is true, $2n$ can always be written in such a way.

Answer (score 1):

Goldbach $\implies\forall{n>1}\exists{p_1,p_2}:$

$2n=p_1+p_2\implies{n}=\dfrac{p_1+p_2}{2}\implies{n}$ is centered between $p_1$ and $p_2$

The "or is itself prime" statement seems redundant...

Comment: Suppose there was a prime number which was not centered between a pair of primes. Then that prime number multiplied by 2 would only be a Goldbach number because it would be the sum of that prime number added to itself.

Comment: @JeffreyYoung: Right, and that prime number would also be centered between itself and itself (i.e., between a pair of primes).